# plotting spatial points over a raster layer in r

Tags: r, plot, spatial, raster

I wish to plot a matrix (temp_matrix) after converting it to a raster object (tempMap). Further, I wish to add few points whose latitude and longitude locations are available to me on the same plot window. I have tried few approaches but none seems to work since the points available are specific locations in lat/long while the raster object I am getting has a different extent. Please help me with this issue. Given below is the sample data for the problem.

```
library(raster)
temp_matrix<-array(NA,c(11,11))
temp_matrix[1,]<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,-6,-6)
temp_matrix[2,]<-c(0,0,0,0,NA,NA,1,0,0,0,0)
temp_matrix[3,]<-c(1,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,0,0)
temp_matrix[4,]<-c(1,1,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0)
temp_matrix[5,]<-c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1)
temp_matrix[6,]<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-1,-1,-1,0,0)
temp_matrix[7,]<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,-1,0,0)
temp_matrix[8,]<-c( NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,-1)
temp_matrix[9,]<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-1,0,0,0)
temp_matrix[10,]<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-1,-1,-2)
temp_matrix[11,]<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-2,-3,-2)
plot(raster(temp_matrix),axes = FALSE,legend=FALSE)
tempMap <- raster(temp_matrix)

# plot the points over this raster layer
point_1<-c(10,10) # should appear on 2nd row from top i.e. over temp_matrix[2,10]
point_2<-c(9,10)  # should appear on 3rd row from top i.e. over temp_matrix[3,10]
point_3<-c(1,10)  # should appear on lowermost row i.e.over temp_matrix[11,10]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set your desired extent, not rely on the default values.

As the help for `raster` states

```
## S4 method for signature 'matrix'
raster(x, xmn=0, xmx=1, ymn=0, ymx=1, crs=NA, template=NULL)
```

with

> - `xmn` ::  minimum x coordinate (left border)
> - `xmx` ::  maximum x coordinate (right border)
> - `ymn` :: minimum y coordinate (bottom border)
> - `ymx` :: maximum y coordinate (top border)

You can set `xmn`, `xmx`, `ymn` and `ymx` to the values you wish (1, 11, 1, 11) in this case)

```
tempMap <- raster(temp_matrix, xmn = 1, xmx = 11, ymn = 1, ymx=11)
plot(tempMap,axes = FALSE,legend=FALSE)
points(c(10,9,1), c(10,10,10))
```

[image]

Comment: this does work for the sample code, however, the original matrix has a dimension (37,72) and when I try to change its extent, the resolution also changes and deforms the original plot. Default resolution is: 0.01388889, 0.02702703  (x, y)
while the new resolution comes out to be: 0.5138889, 1.945946  (x,y). Any idea how can I keep the resolution same or reset it while changing the extent. Thanks in advance.                                                                                                  tempMap <- raster(diffMat,xmn=-14.5,xmx=22.5,ymn=-36,ymx=36)

Comment: I think you have your `x` and `y` reversed. With some dummy data (a 37 row, 72 column matrix called `m`), `raster(m,ymn=-14.5,ymx=22.5,xmn=-36,xmx=36) ` gives a raster with resolution `1,1`

Comment: I reversed them with the assumption that 37 rows should correspond to 37 partitions on y axis although they represent latitudes and similar logic for longitudes dividing x-axis into 72 parts. Although I am still thinking of proper explanation in theory and resolution issue also exists on my machine BUT your answer helped in understanding the concept of raster-extent and plot the points at desired location. THANKS :)

Comment: The conventions for rows/columns are (annoyingly) different, and perhaps inconsistent in images and matrices. See `library(fortunes);fortune(143)`