# Plotting Raster object with points at exact position

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a raster object to which I would like to add points.
However, when I change plot size, by making it full screen for example, the points change their positions.

Is there a way to give them exact positions, independent of plot size?

reproducable code:

`r<- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
plot(r)
points(x=-50,y=20)
points(x=-50,y=-90)`

I'm not allowed to post images. But the lower point gets out of the coloured region when I make the device smaller or moves more into the coloured region when I make the device bigger.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

this problem has been exposed here too: [plotting spatial points over a raster layer in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718915/plotting-spatial-points-over-a-raster-layer-in-r).

I tried to overpass it by creating a SpatialPointsDataFrame:

```
r<- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
plot(r)
points(x=-50,y=20)
points(x=-50,y=-90)


coor1<- data.frame(Lat=-50,Lon=20)


point1 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
  data.frame(coor1$Lon,coor1$Lat),
  data.frame('Landriano')
)

x11()
plot(r)
plot(point1, add=T)
```

The only solution I see is once you overlap the point over the raster you shouldn't change the plot window size. Otherwise the points will be shifted somewhere randomly...